# How to use Split Function with matching functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, split

I tried to use split function code for my project with matching functions but I didn't work perfectly that I want to use on my website with the help jquery and split function code

here Is the example of code

```
  $(".Menu > li > a").each(function() {
             var $this = $(this),
            sp = $this.attr("href").split("/");
            if(!isNaN(sp[0])){
              var count = sp[0],
                  type = sp[1],
                  label = sp[2];
              blockfeeds($this, count, label, type);
            }
    });
```

When i run this code with the help of my matching shortcode is **10/Life/Wrapper** it works fine but the problem with split function
i need that i use this shortcut code to work  this code perfectly and here is the shortcode which i need **Life/Wrapper**

But i tried to work this shortcode **Life/Wrapper** to work then
here is example

```
      $(".Menu > li > a").each(function() {
             var $this = $(this),
            sp = $this.attr("href").split("/");
            if(!isNaN(sp[0])){
              var type = sp[1],
                  label = sp[2];
              blockfeeds($this, 5, label, type);
            }
    });
```

Here when i tried this above code and replace `count = sp[0],` with `count = 5,` it works fine but the shortcode is **/Life/Wrapper** then it works
Why there is '/' when i run the code

Any Body please help me or guide me how to remove this '/' from shortocde **/Life/Wrapper**

so that i can use **Life/Wrapper** without any / in starting

The HTML Code of Matching This Shortcode is here

```
<div class="Menu">
<li>
<a href="Life/Wrapper">Menu</a>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$(".Menu > li > a").each(function() {
    let splits = $(this).attr("href").split("/");
    if(2 === splits.length) {
        let type = splits[0];
        let label = splits[1];
        blockfeeds($(this), 5, label, type);
    }
});
```